# How clearly separate "could be **ed", "has been **ed" and "will be **ed" in the "participle + noun" combinations?

Tags: past-participles, participles

Well, I have the programming examples only, but I suppose it could be reused on the common English.

AFAIK "Imported namespace" could mean:

1. Namespace which *has been* imported
2. Namespace which *will be* imported

I can name the variables like "namespaceWhichHasBeenImported", but if there more concise expression like "Participle + noun" I'll use it herewith the tense must be clear (at least is it the past, present or the future).

Also, I am not sure but maybe the "wrappable entity" besides "entity which could be wrapped" (but not compulsory *will be* wrapped) may also means "entity which will be wrapped". Please confirm or refute it.

Comment: The standard meanings are: *imported namespace* — one which has been imported; *importable namespace* — one which could be imported. Unfortunately, we don't have anything simple for *namespace to be imported*. You could call it *NamespaceToImport*, which I think is slightly better than *to be imported*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a **goose to cook**, then only once you cooked it would you have
a **cooked goose**.  You wouldn’t ever go confusing that one with a goose
that hasn’t been cooked yet, because that would be an **uncooked goose**.
Before you cooked it, your goose was merely ***cookable*** not ***cooked***.

So you started out with a **cookable goose** not a **cooked goose**, and you
wouldn’t ever confuse the two.  A **goose to cook** is never a goose you
*did* cook; it’s one you did not.

Of course not all geese are for cooking, which means you probably want
to separately consider an **uncooked goose**’s ***cookability***. Once you do,
you could then have both **cookable uncooked geese** as well
as **uncookable uncooked geese**.

But you wouldn’t have **cookable cooked geese**, because once your **goose is cooked**, it’s all done: nobody eats
**recooked geese**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "uncooked cookable geese" and "uncooked uncookable geese"?

Comment: Thank you for the great explanations! Understood about "could be cooked" and "has been cooked" part. The last piece of puzzle is "will be [definitely] cooked". If there is no "participle + noun" please say such as.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawa A goose that you intend to cook would be a `goose_to_cook` with an infinitive of purpose, or even that plus a passive participle in   `goose_to_be_cooked_on_Christmas_Day`, but never a  `to_cook_goose` or a `to_be_cooked_goose` with the yet-to-be-done action expressed as an infinitive or with a participle in attributive position before the noun. Although [Latin enjoys a full range of inflected nonfinite forms and verbal nouns derived from verbs in "all" the tenses and voices](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coquo#Conjugation) which you can use that way, English simply does not.